# PHP DOMnode. How to check if it's pair or not?

Tags: php, xml, domdocument, dom-node

I have some tags in XML document:

```
      <kat1>42</kat1>
      <kat2/>
      <kat3/>
```

and if DOMNode $myNode is "kat2"

```
$myNode->nodeValue
```

returns zero instead of null. How to check if it is not paired tag and return NULL if true, else value.

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d7aee6ccf92a3710cca929c4d14224654831f41a)

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d7aee6ccf92a3710cca929c4d14224654831f41a

Code example

Comment: Post it here instead and you'll get proper help.

Comment: I post link to code, which can be executed and checked online.

Comment: If that link gets deleted, your question will have no use for future users.

Answer (score 0):

`<tag />` is the exact same thing as `<tag></tag>` so, all you have to do is check whether or not it's empty. If it's empty it wil be printed as a single tag, if it's not empty it will be be printed with both opening and closing tags.

Comment: $isSingleTag = empty($dach->item($i)->nodeValue) ? true : false;

Comment: shorter variant is `$isSingleTag = empty($dach->item($i)->nodeValue);` but this example will also process when `<kat2/>` and `<kat2></kat2>` and `<kat2>0</kat2>`, so this is not the same, yep? zero value and non-existent value must not be the same. (I think so)

Comment: Good point, how bout `$isSingleTag = empty($dach->item($i)->nodeValue) && $dach->item($i)->nodeValue !== 0;`

Comment: this is not the solution!
`$vals = array(
 'null'    => NULL,
 'zero as string'  => '0',
 'zero as int'  => 0,
);

echo '-----------------------<br/>'; 

foreach($vals as $key => $val){
 echo '<pre>';
 echo "is empty '{$key}'?".( empty($val) ) ? 'YES' : 'NO';
 echo '</pre>';
}

echo '-----------------------<br/>'; 
/*
RESULT IS 
-----------------------
YES
YES
YES
-----------------------
*/`